# Swift & XCode - How to modify buttons width

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

Recently, I have needed to split this button so that they are constrained with the same height but different widths, split 60 - 40, along the screen. They also have to respond to any Iphone / Ipad screen. I currently have them set within a stack view so that they are positioned correctly yet this is not optimal and do not allow me to modify their width.

Is there a XCode creator solution? If not, is there a solution in code?

Images:

Goal:
[image]

Current Hierarchy:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Proportional Widths.

1. Set the constraints on your stack view so it is positioned and sized where you want it.
2. Ctrl-Click-Drag from the `Clear` button to the `Start` button and select `Equal Widths`
3. Edit the resulting constraint and set the Multiplier to `40:60` (for clarity... it could just as well be `4:6:` or `2:3`). The `Equal Width` label on the constraint will change to `Proportional Width`
4. Set the Stack View to `Alignment: Fill` / `Distribution: Fill` / `Spacing: (however much you want)`

That should do it :)